# Create regex validator for IDs like "<car>-<model>-id"

Tags: regex

I have a list of IDs that look like `<car>-<model>-id`, for example:

`truck-silverado-id`
`truck-big-ranger-id`
`compact-civic-id`

I'm trying to make a regex express to validate the ID. My validation is matching non-ids. Can anyone assist? Here is what I have so far (reduced options for simplicity):

`/(truck|truck-big|compact)(-(silverado|ranger|civic)-id)?/gi`

Comment: Add anchors,  see `^(truck|truck-big|compact)(-(silverado|ranger|civic)-id)?$` at https://regex101.com/r/iYufAC/1

Comment: Is the regexp actually reflecting the `-id` being mandatory? I think you would like `(truck|truck-big|compact)(-(silverado|ranger|civic)?)-id`

Comment: Thanks guys, yep the `-id` is mandatory. I think the anchors will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding the suggestions into an answer, you need anchors on the regex, and you need to make `-id` required.

`/^(truck|truck-big|compact)(-(silverado|ranger|civic))?-id$/gi`